# Rails search for posts by label (tags)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, join

I'm trying to implement search function on a recipe based on the tags it was given. I'm running into issues trying to understand how joining them works and where the code is placed exactly.

This is my Recipe model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :ingredients
   has_many :directions
   has_many :labels

   def self.search(search)
     where("recipe_name ILIKE ? OR recipe_description ILIKE ? 
     OR serving_size ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#
     {search}%", "%#{search}%") 
   end  

end
```

I got it working so i'm able to search by fields like `recipe_name` `recipe_description` and `serving_size`

What i'm trying to accomplish next is search the recipe based on the many labels it has:

This is my index action for `RecipeController`

```
    def index
      @recipes = Recipe.all 
      if params[:search]
          @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      else 
          @recipes = Recipe.all.order("recipe_name ASC")
      end
   end
```

I tried a few ways to go about it but i can't seem to figure it out, I've read the `joins` method on the activeRecord guide.

Here is something i've already tried, not sure why im not following...

```
    def self.search(search)
      where("recipe_name ILIKE ? OR #{Recipe.joins(:labels).where(labels.label_name = "?")} ILIKE ? OR serving_size ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%") 
    end
```

Can anyone point out where i am going wrong in my understanding of using joins to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

The correct syntax for what you are trying to achieve is:

```
def self.search(search)
  joins(:labels).where("recipe_name ILIKE ? OR labels.label_name ILIKE ? OR serving_size ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

Just be aware that you may get duplicate results from this query. To fix that, append a `#uniq` call to the end of it:

```
def self.search(search)
  joins(:labels).where("recipe_name ILIKE ? OR labels.label_name ILIKE ? OR serving_size ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%").uniq
end
```

You can take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) Rails guide for more details.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. Great answer :)